# CMake get a cache variables list from inside a CMakeLists.txt script

Tags: cmake, cmake-language, cmakelists-options

I'd like to know if there's a way to get a list of cached variables from inside a CMakeLists.txt script. I mean, having something like this:

```
cmake -S . -B build -DMY_VAR1=hello -DMY_VAR2=there
```

and, within my CMakeLists.txt

```
option(MY_VAR3 "a cache setting" ON)
```

is there a way to get a list var MY_CACHE_LIST containing MY_VAR1, MY_VAR2 and MY_VAR3 and all other cache variables from inside the CMakeLists.txt script itself?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of cache variables is contained in the [CACHE_VARIABLES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/CACHE_VARIABLES.html) property for a directory. It could be extracted as follows:

```
get_directory_property(cache_vars CACHE_VARIABLES)
message(STATUS "List of CACHE variables: ${cache_vars}")
```

---

Aside from printing the list of these variables, by using name of each variable it is possible to extract its value and extract other properties listed under [Properties on Cache Entries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-cache-entries).

Comment: why is that list so much longer than the output of `cmake -L`?

Comment: @stefanct: The option `-L` outputs only those CACHE variables, which are neither INTERNAL nor ADVANCED. This is described in the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-L-A-H)